# how can I configure an Access Point on a Lan Network that has only one working IP Address?

Tags: access-point

I can connect to Internet via Ethernet-cable (Port in wall , no access to the main router) and have those configurations and with any device connecting to this Lan port it is always the same IP address given.

```
IPv4-Adresse : 134.102.9.7
Subnetmask: 255.255.255.224
standardgateway : 134.102.9.30
```

I configured my Access Point so that he has :

```
IPv4-Adresse : 134.102.9.2
Subnetmask: 255.255.255.224
standardgateway : 134.102.9.30
DHCP disabled.
```

When connecting with wifi on this AP I end up getting the `134.102.9.7` IP address and I can connect to internet this way , but the problem is that I can only connect one device that will have this one working IP address.

I know using an Access Point is different than connecting one PC with Ethernet and share a WIFI network that will have a different network configuration (not the same IP address Pool).

Is there a way to do so with an Access Point? like has an Ip address on Lan port but shares the Wifi on another network (different than `134.102.9.X`) ? or is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to plug a router into your Ethernet port. Routers provide [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), which gives you the ability to connect many devices.

It is common for one router to connect to another, which connects to another, in an ever-branching fan-out of connection points.